# Magento 1.9.3.6 duplicated url rewrites after each reindex

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, reindex

In my Magento 1.9.3.6 installation I have a duplicate url problem.
At every reindex, all the url rewrites are regenerated like magento didn't read that they were already created.
Regenerating the indexes 4 times, I get 4 clones of ALL url rewrite.

I tried different solutions, the truncate of the table, the application of some patches etc.. but Magento continues to generate only duplicates.

Going to change a category url key or a product url key, Magento doesn't create the redirect from the old url to the new url but will simply create the link from the new url to the parametric target id (catalog / product / view / 50 /)

I clarify that the duplicate url are all always like url key -> parameter url. Never in the old form url -> new url. 
This ISN'T the problem of the numeric parameters inserted in the suffix of the url, but something else. 
Is it some known bug?

What's the class or function that allows Magento to check if an url rewrites exists?

[image]